# How does Stanford NLP identify "it" is being referred to whom?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, text-classification

Let's say we have two sentences:

1. Jacob is going to watch a movie with Justin.
2. He will be back by 10 pm.

How does Stanford NLP identify "he" refers to Jacob and not Justin?

Comment: There is no single right answer, both interpretations are possible. You'd need more context to make a single decision, but as it stands it's a random choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called `coreference resolution` and is a well-studied problem in NLP. As such, there are many possible ways to do it. Stackoverflow is not the right venue for a literature review, but here are a few links to get you started

- [http://www-labs.iro.umontreal.ca/~felipe/IFT6010-Hiver2015/Presentations/Abbas-Coreference.pdf](http://www-labs.iro.umontreal.ca/%7Efelipe/IFT6010-Hiver2015/Presentations/Abbas-Coreference.pdf)
- https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/coref.shtml and links therein